# How to add dapper query parameters in a loop

Tags: asp.net-core, dapper

When add query parameters for dapper in a loop，like this:

```
if (model.UserGroupId != null && model.UserGroupId.Count>0)
{
    var list = model.UserGroupId;
    sql += " and ( CHARINDEX(','+@group_id+',',','+mem.group_id+',')>0 ";
    paras.Add("group_id", list[0].Trim());
    for (var i = 1; i < list.Count(); i++)
    {
        string data = "@group_id" + i;
        sql += " or CHARINDEX('," + data+ ",',','+mem.group_id+',')>0 ";
        paras.Add(data, list[i].Trim());
    }
    sql += " )";
}
```

it does not report errors, but the query results are incorrect. I can't use dynamic @ as a result of searching data. How can I solve this problem?

If I use this it can search correctly：

```
if (model.UserGroupId != null && model.UserGroupId.Count > 0)
{
    var list = model.UserGroupId;
    sql += " and ( CHARINDEX(','+@group_id+',',','+mem.group_id+',')>0 ";
    paras.Add("group_id", list[0].Trim());
    for (var i = 1; i < list.Count(); i++)
    {
        //  string data = "@group_id" + i;
        sql += " or CHARINDEX('," + list[i].Trim() + ",',','+mem.group_id+',')>0 ";
        // paras.Add(data, list[i].Trim());
    }
    sql += " )";
}
```

But it has SQL injection problems.

Comment: *Please* don't do this! If you are using SQL server, use a stored procedure that accepts a table-valued parameter; for other RDBMs, use a stored procedure that accepts a comma-delimited string and splits it into its components inside the procedure.

Comment: i have solved it by dapper,it like this:

Comment: var list = model.UserGroupId;
                sql += " and ( CHARINDEX(','+@group_id+',',','+mem.group_id+',')>0 ";
                paras.Add("group_id", list[0].Trim());
                for (var i = 1; i < list.Count(); i++)
                {
                   sql += " or CHARINDEX(','+@group_id"+i+"+',',','+mem.group_id+',')>0 ";
                    paras.Add("@group_id" + i, list[i].Trim());
                }
                sql += " )";

Answer (score 0):

```
           var list = model.UserGroupId;
            sql += " and ( CHARINDEX(','+@group_id+',',','+mem.group_id+',')>0 ";
            paras.Add("group_id", list[0].Trim());
            for (var i = 1; i < list.Count(); i++)
            {
               **sql += " or CHARINDEX(','+@group_id"+i+"+',',','+mem.group_id+',')>0 ";
                paras.Add("@group_id" + i, list[i].Trim());**
            }
            sql += " )";
```

it can search rightly